# Stored procedure get request returns empty, but when called in SSMS, it works

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sql-server

I've got this stored procedure that I need to call in my reactjs/axios frontend, and I'm using a nodejs API with express and mssql packages to do so.

But for some reason, it just returns an empty result when called from node, but if I copy the same query into SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine, it does return a few entries as expected.

This is the code in React:

```
Axios.get('http://' + urlCustom + ':3002/api/consultRS', {params:{agency:inputAgency, since:dateS, upTo:dateU}}).then((response) =>{
          console.log(response.data);
      })
```

It's doing a `GET` request, sending the parameters that the stored procedure needs, a numeric code for agency, and two dates.

When it gets to node, the code is:

```
app.get('/api/consultRS', (req, res) =>{
  sql2.connect(sqlConfigS, function(err){
    if(err){
     console.log('connection error is: ' + err);res.send(err);
    }
     var request = new sql.Request();
     var query = "exec prc.procedureRN '" + req.query.agency +"','"+req.query.dateS+"','"+req.query.dateU+"'";
     request.query(query, function(err,records){
       console.log('the query is: ' + query);
       if(err){
         console.log('error= ' + err);
         res.send(err);}
       else{
         console.log(records);
         res.send(records);}})
  })
})
```

And the result I'm getting in the node console is always

> The query is: exec prc.procedureRN '00001','04/10/2023','04/10/2023'
>
> { recordsets: [ [] ], recordset: [], output: {}, rowsAffected: [ 0 ] }

However if I were to copy the query from the same nodejs console that comes back with the "the query is:" log, and paste it in SQL Server Management Studio, so basically in this example

```
exec prc.procedureRN '00001','04/10/2023','04/10/2023'
```

it works as expected.

Tried checking the sqlConfigS just in case something with the connection was wrong but that was fine, tried also with a different stored procedure in the same server but a different db, (used a different sqlConfig object to connect to a different db), and using the same exact format for the request, it works fine. I get all the entries both in nodejs and in SQL Server Management Studio.

I'd really like to know what's causing this, and if possible how to fix it.

Could it be an async function issue, and it's returning before it got the results, so it goes back as empty? but if that's so, why does it work with a different stored procedure if the rest is the same.

Comment: **DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION TO SUPPLY PARAMETER DATA!**

Comment: Just a guess but sometimes you need to add `set nocount on` at the beginning of procedure cause it messes up the result outputs.